# ios add color alpha to background view

Tags: ios, uiview

I have added a pop-up selector to an iPad App, and when it's popped up, I would like the view behind to have a `lightGray` alpha added so the pop-up stands out.  I've been able to add the color to the entire background `UIView`, however I have some images within the `UIView` which are not impacted by adding the color.  Is there an simple way to add the background color to the entire view including the images?

Here is my code:

```
IBOutlet UIView *viewVersion; //this is the pop-up view

- (IBAction)openSelector:(UIButton *)sender {
    viewVersion.hidden = NO;
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0]];
    [viewVersion setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Comment: Are you saying about adding a shadowLayer? in that case use google shadow for UIview and you'll get results

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason why some view objects (ie. the images) are not covered by the grey area is because the view hierarchy (think layers in photoshop) has those objects above your grey area view. You should bring the grey area view to the front of the hierarchy and then immediately afterwards, bring your popup view to the front of the hierarchy. This will ensure all other views are below them on the hierarchy and thus will be drawn over all other views.

I believe there is a method for this called 'bringSubviewToFront'. Here is a code snippet to get you started:

```
    UIView* aview = [UIView new];
    [aview.superview bringSubviewToFront:aview];
```

Comment: So would want to bring the self.view to the Front, correct?